# New line in .ics using generated PHP

Tags: php, newline, icalendar

I am creating a script which will generate a .ics file in PHP however when I try to add more than one line to the DESCRIPTION: addition to the attachment it shows up as a new line entirely in the .ics
What I type into the php

```
$var .= "DESCRIPTION: Line1\nLine2" . PHP_EOL;
```

What is shown in the .ics file

```
DESCRIPTION: Line1
Line2
```

Any ideas on how to get around this problem when generating the .ics code in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a description with more than 1 line in an application that allows you to make ics files. Then open it in notepad++/sublime or something and see how they parse it.

Comment: The issue is non escaping of "\n". Question could be worded a little better ;)

Comment: you should also consider that lines cannot be more than 75 char long and need to be wrapped see [rfc5545 3.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.1)